# how to join named scopes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to join my named scopes as I generate them with an array.
how wouldI do that , i can't join named scopes, is there a better way to do this?

```
 scope :search, ->(attrs_for_search,params) do
   if attrs_for_search.present?
     params_to_search_on = params.keys & attrs_for_search
     params_to_search_on.collect{|x| where("#{x} ILIKE ?", "%#{params[x]}%")     }
   else                 
     none               
   end                  
 end   

 Contact.search(%w[email],{'email => 'jason'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain scopes when you return an array.

You can:

1. Try returning a relation:

   ```
   results = params_to_search_on.collect{|x| where("#{x} ILIKE ?", "%#{params[x]}%")     }
   where(id: results.flatten.map(&:id))
   ```

   I have not tested this, but I think you will need `flatten` because results is an array of relations `[rel_1,_rel_2]`

   Then you can use/chain/attach-a-bunch-of scopes like this:

   ```
   Contact.search(attrs, params).other_scope.another_scope(with_params)
   ```
2. You may want to read about full text search, to expand this topic, I would need to know the DB you are using.

Comment: i don't want to return an array, i just want to attach a bunch of scopes to the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can create a scope and use the 'send' method to join the scopes.

```
scope :search, ->(field, value) do
   where("#{field} LIKE ?", "%#{value}%")
end

def self.multi_search(params)
    result = nil
    params_to_search_on = params.keys
    params_to_search_on.each do |k|
      if result.nil?
        result = Message.send(:search, k, params[k])
      else
        result = result.send(:search, k, params[k])
      end
    end
    result
end
```

Hopes this help you.